# Quarternionic Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus, quaternions

What is/are the current understanding/opinions about Quarternionic Analysis as a generalization of Complex Analysis with respect to a "Quarternionic Residue Calculus" (if such a thing exists)? i.e. does a "quarternionic residue calculus" exist, and if not what are the opinions that this might be useful, if indeed possible?

For example, residue calculus is great if we can find a "nice" contour to work with, but sometimes this does not seem possible. I'm just wondering if a Quarternionic Analysis would allow for 4-dimensional "contours" (i.e. surfaces) in the "Quarternion-plane" (i.e. 4-dimensional space) that might allow the evaluation of definite integrals which seem otherwise unsolvable by the residue calculus of complex analysis.

Comment: I think I remember reading that holomorphic functions in the quaternionic sense are constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while back, when asking myself the same question, I found [this website](http://www.zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/math/quaternions/analysis.html) to be very informative. The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_analysis) was also useful, if only for its bibilography.

You might also have better luck if you search for "hypercomplex analysis." In googlebooks I found [Generalized Analytic Automorphic Forms in Hypercomplex Spaces By Rolf S. Krausshar](http://books.google.com/books?id=mr6nS5CrnFMC&pg=PA22&dq=quaternionic+residue+calculus&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8O3wUo3GKcruyQH7qoDIDg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=quaternionic%20residue%20calculus&f=false). On page 21 it states Theorem 1.23 (Residue theorem) for certain finite dimensional differentiable manifolds, and on page 22 it says:

*Also the residue theorem can be generalized to the more general context dealing with manifolds of singularities. See [61,63] for the quaternionic case...*

I would give you the two references but I can't see the bibliography. If I were in your position I'd definitely find this book :)

I did not get very deep into the subject: I just satisfied my curiosity about whether or not people have been thinking about analyticity, differentiation, integration and all other things from real and complex analysis in the context of the quaternions, and it appears that they have.

Comment: I found the references:

[61] R. Futter. Uber vierfachperiodische Funktionen. Monatshefte Math. Phys. 48 (193), pp. 161-169.
[63] R. Fueter. Functions of a Hyper Complex Variable. Lecture notes written and supplemented by E. Bareiss, Math. Inst. Univ. Zurich, Fall Semester 1948/49.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question that I actually posed to myself as well. For this reason I started to research more about the subject and the related literature/research papers exc.

Once I felt like I satisfied my curiosity, however, I noticed that finding resources about the subject was quite difficult, and that there were several interesting approaches to the subject that were all inter-connected.

For this reasons I decided to join all the most important results of quaternionic analysis in a short monography (around 300 pages long), that [I made available for free here.](https://github.com/hsnborn22/quaternionic-analysis)

As I mentioned before as well, there are several approaches to doing analysis with quaternionic functions. The first one is due to Fueter, and the central object of study of the latter is the notion of $\textbf{Fueter-regular functions}$, a class of functions for which several quaternionic analogues of important results in complex analysis have been proved. The first one that I will report is known as the $\textbf{Cauchy-Riemann-Fueter equations}$, which has both a right and a left version (the non-commutativity of quaternions forces us to define left and right derivatives of quaternionic functions, as well as a notion of left regular and right regular functions).

The left Cauchy-Riemann-Fueter equations state that a function of a quaternionic variable $f: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ is left regular at $q_0 \in \mathbb{H}$ if and only if, in $q_0$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +j\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0 $$

In a similar way the right Cauchy-Riemann-Fueter equations state that a function $f:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ is right regular iff:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}i +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}k = 0 $$

Now you might ask: what even is a regular function of a quaternionic variable? This notion has been defined equivalently in different ways (for example C.A Deavours defines them directly as a class of functions that respect a quaternionic integral equation that resembles cauchy's theorem, for more info check [you can read his full paper here](https://theworld.com/%7Esweetser/quaternions/ps/deavours.pdf)), however here I will provide the definition given in the famous [survey paper by A.Sudbery](https://theworld.com/%7Esweetser/quaternions/ps/Quaternionic-analysis.pdf).

A function of a quaternionic variable $f$ is said to be left-regular in $q \in \mathbb{H}$ if it's 1-time differentiable in the classical sense (i.e in the classical $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4 $ sense) and there exists a quaternion $f_l'(q)$, which we call $\textbf{the left derivative of f in q}$, such that:

$$d(dq \wedge dq f) = Dq f'_l(q)$$

Where here $Dq$ is a quaternionic differential form defined as

$$Dq := dx \wedge dy \wedge dz - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}e_i dt \wedge dx_j \wedge dx_k$$
Where here I used Einstein's notation and the levi-civita symbol to write it more compactly.

Understanding what this equation means intuitively requires a good knowledge of the genetic development of hypercomplex analysis and quaternionic analysis and here I don't have the time to explain everything in depth; for this you can [check my monography](https://github.com/hsnborn22/quaternionic-analysis), that I also linked above. In part it boils down to the important geometric properties of the Dq differential form, and the proofs of theese are provided in Sudbery's paper.

A quaternionic analogue of Cauchy's theorem is valid for 4-parallelelipeds and smooth 3-chains homologous to 0 in the singular homology of the open set where our function is defined (and also valid for rectifiable contours).

$$\int_C Dq f(q) = 0$$
Where $f:U \to \mathbb{H}$ is a left-regular quaternionic function, $Dq$ is our form from before and $C$ is our smooth 3-chain homologous to 0 in the singular diff. homology of $U$.

Analogues of Cauchy's integral formula, Liouville's theorem, Taylor and Laurent series expansions also hold, but including these here as well would make the reply way too long; if you want to know more [I encourage you to check the resources I listed](https://github.com/hsnborn22/quaternionic-analysis). I hope you will find this answer helpful even though this discussion is quite old.